# Search value for key in string-array android

Tags: android

i have a string-array in my res/values/strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="my_list">  
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
</string-array>
```

i am accessing it in my application as and comparing it with my value in loop.

```
String[] myStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_list);
for(int i=0;i<myStrings.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(myStrings[i]);
}
```

Now i need the search the items according to key to get the respective item.Example

```
<string-array name="my_list">  
    <item name="one">Item1</item>
    <item name="two">Item2</item>
</string-array>
```

if my search hay key "one" then get its corresponding value(Item1).

How to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is a Map like data structure. Sadly there is currently no way to create a Map of Strings through XML like that.

You could either do it all in Java or write your map in a Raw XML file and read/parse that in to a map at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way now? Or shall I be still Sad?

Comment: Still be sad :( No way to do this still as far as I know. I still use AlexV's method

Answer (score 22):

Well, I've done it using two arrays. Easy to manage as well.

One for Keys:

```
<string-array name="codes">
        <item>AC</item>
        <item>AD</item>
        <item>AE</item>
</string-array>
```

One for Values:

```
<string-array name="names">
        <item>Ascension</item>
        <item>Andorra</item>
        <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
</string-array>
```

And the search method.

```
private String getCountryByCode(String code) {
        int i = -1;
        for (String cc: getResources().getStringArray(R.array.codes)) {
            i++;
            if (cc.equals(code))
                break;
        }
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names)[i];
    }
```

Note: The code above will not work if items inside the two lists was unordered. So make sure you arranged the items.

Comment: I like this solution.  Not super ideal but works well.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to achive that, but you can do something like that:

```
   <string-array name="my_array">
        <item>key1|value1</item>
        <item>key2|value2</item>
   </string-array>
```

And have a util function something like:

```
Map<String, String> getKeyValueFromStringArray(Context ctx) {
    String[] array = ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String str : array) {
        String[] splittedItem = str.split("|");
        result.put(splittedItem[0], splittedItem[1])
    }
    return result
}
```

It's look a little bit hacky, but in general, because you have control over your dictionary - probably it not so awful idea.

Comment: +1. `|`->`\\|`. As side note, from time to time I use something like Guava's [Splitter](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) to avoid extra regexp for such simple case.

Answer (score 4):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="area_key">
    <item>北</item>
    <item>中</item>
    <item>南</item>
  </string-array>
  <integer-array name="area_value">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
  </integer-array>
</resources>
```

Java file:

```
String[] areaKey = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.area_key);
int[] areaValue = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.area_value);
HashMap<String, Integer> areas = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < areaKey.length; i++) {
  areas.put(areaKey[i], areaValue[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
The decision for me was to create many strings in xml-file (not string arrays) and to create String[] array in code. It looks like this:

```
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DMCBrowser.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.title_playlist);
    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[] { getResources().getString(R.string.watch_all),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.select_items) };
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (items[which].equals(getResources().getString(R.string.watch_all))) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Watch all");
                        } else if (items[which].equals(getResources().getString(R.string.select_items))) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Select items");
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
```

Although it does not look much compact, we can differ one item from another not only by non-understandable identifier like 1 or 2, but by human-readable android R-id. If i would like to change item order, it will be very easy.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to do this is to make an array of arrays with XML as shown below. Then the native functions make it pretty easy to get the array with the named index you want and get the string inside it.

```
<string-array name="one">
    <item>"Item 1"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="two">
    <item>"Item 2"</item>
</string-array>

<array name="my_list">
    <item>@array/one</item>
    <item>@array/two</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in java code:

```
 public static HashMap<Integer, String> getAll()
 {
            HashMap<Integer, String> items = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            items.put(0, "item 1");
            items.put(1, "item 2");
            items.put(2, "item 3");
            return items;
 }

 public static Integer getKey(Map hm, String value) {
            for (Object o : hm.keySet()) {
                if (hm.get(o).equals(value)) {
                    return (Integer)o;
                }
            }
            return 0;
 }
```

and bind to spinner:

```
Spinner spn_items = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spn_items);
ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getAll().values().toArray());    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spn_items.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make resource of your string array like below to show as hashmap kind :

```
<string-array name="list_websites">
        <item>
            <string name="title">Amazon</string>
            <string name="isChecked">0</string>
        </item>
        <item>
            <string name="title">eBay</string>
            <string name="isChecked">0</string>
        </item>
        <item>
            <string name="title">Sam\'s Club</string>
            <string name="isChecked">0</string>
        </item>
        <item>
            <string name="title">Wallmart</string>
            <string name="isChecked">0</string>
        </item>
        <item>
            <string name="title">Best Buy</string>
            <string name="isChecked">0</string>
        </item>
        <item>
            <string name="title">Rekuten</string>
            <string name="isChecked">0</string>
        </item>
</string-array>
```

Now above code can be parsed as ArrayList of HashMap kind.

Comment: Could you add a code example of how you parse this from the resources file? I get empty string arrays with the following using your example resource: ```String[] config = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_websites);```

Comment: Tag <string> can not appear inside <string-array>, only <item>