# Get attribute name from string array

Tags: android, android-xml

I have string array that looks like this:

```
<string-array name="USA">
    <item name="NY">001</item>
    <item name="LA">002</item>
    <item name="WA">003</item>
</string-array>
```

I can get those numbers by:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int arryid = res.getIdentifier("USA", "array", getPackageName());
String[] numbers = res.getStringArray(arryid);
```

But how can I also get the names (NY,LA,WA)?
Note that I have a lot of counties... Maybe use different approach?

Comment: You can make HashMap instead. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032780/3022836)

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256514/search-value-for-key-in-string-array-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) there is no `name` attribute for an `<item>`.

So I don't think there will be any way to get those keys.

However, if you want to get name of `string` or `string-array`, you can get it programmatically but not for the `<item>`.

Answer (score 4):

As "001" is just the index, why not simply use that?

```
<string-array name="USA">
    <item>NY</item>
    <item>LA</item>
</string-array>
```

Then just use `index + 1` for the position:

```
String[] usaStates = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.USA);

int index = 0;

String firstStateName = usaStates[index];
int firstStatePosition = (index + 1);
```

That aside, you can use two arrays and merge them into a `HashMap`:

```
<string-array name="USA">
    <item>NY</item>
    <item>LA</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="USA_pos">
    <item>001</item>
    <item>002</item>
</string-array>

String[] usaStates = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.USA);
String[] usaStatePositions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.USA_pos);

Map <String, String> map = new HashMap<>(usaStates.length);

for (int i = 0; i < usaStates.length; i++) {
    map.put(usaStates[i], usaStatePositions[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.USA);
```

to get data from array use.

```
numbers[id]
```

add array like this.

```
<string-array name="USA">
    <item>NY</item>
    <item>LA</item>
    <item>WA</item>
</string-array>
```