# Android: get name of string resource used in string-array

Tags: android, arrays, xml

I have a small question.

> My string.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Months -->
    <string name="january">January</string>
    <string name="february">February</string>
    <string name="march">March</string>
    <string name="april">April</string>
    <string name="may">May</string>
    <string name="june">June</string>
    <string name="july">July</string>
    <string name="august">August</string>
    <string name="september">September</string>
    <string name="october">October</string>
    <string name="november">November</string>
    <string name="december">December</string>
</resources>
```

> And my months.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="months">
        <item>@string/january</item>
        <item>@string/february</item>
        <item>@string/march</item>
        <item>@string/april</item>
        <item>@string/may</item>
        <item>@string/june</item>
        <item>@string/july</item>
        <item>@string/august</item>
        <item>@string/september</item>
        <item>@string/october</item>
        <item>@string/november</item>
        <item>@string/december</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I set the months.xml for my spinner.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sn_months"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:entries="@array/months"/>
```

Now, i want to get the string's names of the items like january, february,...NOT January, February,... in the spinner's onItemSelected using the item's position. How can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256514/search-value-for-key-in-string-array-android

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the name of resource used such as `january` from `@string/january`. Not possible. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @EugenPechanec. I will find another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
   String yearnam=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on string value for comparison, you should use `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` as it will return the selected item's index value.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change your input like you want.

```
<resources>
<!-- Months -->
<string name="january">january</string>
<string name="february">february</string>
<string name="march">march</string>
<string name="april">april</string>
<string name="may">may</string>
<string name="june">june</string>
<string name="july">july</string>
<string name="august">august</string>
<string name="september">september</string>
<string name="october">october</string>
<string name="november">november</string>
<string name="december">december</string>
```

Or

2) Create a custom View by extending Spinner
   change the attributre loading behaviour